# jQuery UI AutoComplete parsing data from variable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, autocomplete

I am attempting to use the jQuery UI Autocomplete, and just can't seem to put two and two together.

I have a php page that is used for all json data requests. I use a switch statement to determine which function to fire off when a request is made, using post to pass this data to the php page, ie; "AutoComplete" is passed to the page, which then tells it to retrieve a particular table from my database, then encode it into json.

The data is formatted as such: ["1":"Email", "2":"Hosting"] and so forth. There are a variable number of items in the json data, but always with the key=>value pair. I need the key to be the value of the field, and the value to be displayed in the autocomplete list. (The data order can be reversed if need be, this is just an example).

I don't need or want the autocomplete feature to hit this database every time someone types some characters in the box, so I'm attempting to just generate a static list of the options needed for this field and assign these to a javascript object for use with autocomplete().

```
function myFunction (DataType, ID) {
    $j.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        cache: 'false',
        url: 'json.php',
        data: {jsonFunction:DataType},
        success: function(data){ 
               $j(ID).autocomplete({ source: [data] });
             }
        });
};
```

The function is then called in my document.ready() function:

```
myFunction ("AutoComplete", "input#Type");
```

So what I need is to be able to create a variable from an ajax request that autocomplete can use as its options. I just can't figure out how to get this to work! I've tried several different methods to no avail, including parsing through the data with several examples I've seen here and elsewhere. The documentation for the ui autocomplete states that you can use an array with key value pairs, but it just doesn't like my data no matter how its formatted.

I'm missing something obvious, I'm sure.

Comment: Update, this was never resolved. I abandoned using the autocomplete jquery-ui piece as I could not get it to work correctly. I instead have switched to using a programatically generated select box. :(

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, it's really bad practice, but you could use eval(). Just use javascripts quick-object notation (the braces like jQuery uses)

A better solution - cache your database (assumption) queries

Comment: I'll look into caching my database query. That might do the trick. I want to remove as much needless load off my servers as possible but still offer dynamic features such as this autocomplete.

Comment: It makes more sense to cache your queries than try to do something fancy with javascript. SQL is a generally fast language (name another language that can search 1M records in milliseconds :)). I don't know your server model, but look into Doctrine. It automatically optimizes queries and caching for you. It's a PHP ORM that I use quite frequently

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the `dataType` option of the ajax call to json?  See the doc here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Yes, I have done that. It didn't seem to make a difference. It seems to be that autocomplete() can't parse json data itself. I can't figure out how to clean the data up for autocomplete() to be able to use it. The documentation on it is sparse at best, and I've seen several answers here that talk about parsing through it manually, I just can't get it to work for me. The best I've got from this widget yet is all of the options appearing on a single line under the text field.